# Qi Battery Pack

Tags: battery

I am trying to build a bot that is "always on". I will be using a qi platform and am looking for a battery that charges through Qi. I've found several batteries that can charge your phone through Qi, but I am looking for one that charges itself through Qi. Any clue where I can find one like that? As a second question, do you think such an idea would work? Any foreseeable problems?

Comment: What do you mean by "charges itself through Qi"? The Qi has transmitter - a charging station and a receiver - battery.

Comment: Well, right now with my qi charging station, I place my phone on it for the phone to charge. I want to find a battery that will charge when I put it on the qi charging station.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Serj Sagan, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Qi receiver, that will allow you to transfer energy from a charging station to your robot. Charging a battery will be a separate task. Adafruit has a [module](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1901) capable of providing 5V and 500mA. Or you can go for a complete wireless power bank with USB output. This will also give you 5V that you can use to power up your robot.

Comment: This "complete wireless power bank with USB output" would be continually charged by Qi? I was not able to find such a one... on that Adafruit site... could you link to one please?